# Looping through HTML table checked checkboxes using php

Tags: php

i have a similar thread using javascript but i found some problem and some bugs. so i changed to  php

so far this is my code

```
if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $check) {
        //get the html data beside the checked checkboxes

    }
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Nothing checked")';
        echo '</script>'; 
    }
```

and my stripped html code

```
<tr>
                                <td><?php echo $r['Name'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $r['Age'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $r['Address'] ?></td>

                                <td><input name="check[]" type="checkbox"  ></td>
                            </tr>
```

i wan't to get the data on the same row where a checkbox is checked. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the POST data, and assign $r[NAME] = VALUE

For the PHP code:

```
    array $r;
    foreach($_POST as $post=>$value) {
        //get the html data beside the checked checkboxes
        $r[ $post] = $value;
        } 
    }
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Nothing checked")';
        echo '</script>'; 
    }
```

Assuming that the HTML  part your referring to is the result page
For the HTML:

```
<tr>
                                <td><?php echo $r['Name'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $r['Age'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $r['Address'] ?></td>

                            </tr>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate sir? or to be exact. what code do i need to get the data of a html table using php. kindly explain clearly sir. english is not my language. thank you, i tried the code above and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update OP  to show what the desired outcome is?

Answer (score 0):

First, lets add some data:

```
<?php

$data = [
  '111' => [
    'Name' => 'John',
    'Age' => '25',
    'Address' => 'Baker street, 11'
  ],
  '222' => [
    'Name' => 'Mary',
    'Age' => '19',
    'Address' => 'Elm street, 14'
  ],
  '333' => [
    'Name' => 'Nick',
    'Age' => '23',
    'Address' => '64th stree, 2'
  ]
];

?>
```

Output all data items and set checks from previous posted data:

```
<form method="POST">
<table>
  <?php foreach($data as $id => $item): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $item['Name'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $item['Age'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $item['Address'] ?></td>
    <td><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="<?= $id; ?>"
      <?php if (isset($_POST['check']) && in_array($id, $_POST['check'])): ?>
      checked="checked"
      <?php endif; ?>/></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php if (empty($_POST['check'])): ?>
<script>alert("Nothing checked");</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You'll get reloaded page with properly marked checkboxes after the form submission.

Comment: what is want to do sir is  get the data on the same row where a checkbox is checked.

Comment: @knowmeifyou You got it there.

Comment: can you show me sample code in jsfiddle sir to solve my problem. i really dont understand. i understand a code better when it's an example

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, create a test index.php file, copy whole code to it and request the page by your browser.